# Java prompt that work on Windows but not Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, package, classpath

It is said that Java is portable regardless of the OS. But here is my doubt: 
why the java prompts work perfectly in windows but, in my case, fails to execute the java prompt.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
c:
--|temp
-----|JavaSDKv2
--------|com
-----------|impinj
--------------|octanesdk
-----------------|samples
--------------------|(.java files)
--------------------|(.class files)
--------|OctaneSDKJava-1.20.2.240-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Example:
(In windows 8, in the cmd)

```
    C:\temp>cd JavaSDKv2
    C:\temp\JavaSDKv2>javac com\impinj\octanesdk\samples\*.java    -classpath      OctaneSDK
    Java-1.20.2.240-jar-with-dependencies.jar

    C:\temp\JavaSDKv2>
```

(therefore no error and each java file with a class defined has now a .class file for each class defined in the .java files )

```
C:\temp\JavaSDKv2>java -Dhostname=192.168.2.203 -classpath OctaneSDKJava-1.20.2. 240-jar-with-dependencies.jar;. com.impinj.octanesdk.samples.RfDoppler 
Connecting to 192.168.2.203 
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.mina.filter.execut or.ExecutorFilter). 
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Press Enter to exit.  
EPC: 0100 0000 0000 9950 0000 0000 Reader_ip:    192.168.2.203 doppler: .5625

EPC: 0100 0000 0000 9950 0000 0000 Reader_ip: 192.168.2.203 doppler: 3.0

EPC: 0100 0000 0000 9950 0000 0000 Reader_ip: 192.168.2.203 doppler: -6.6875
```

(and this goes on without any problem)

Then I use Ubuntu (in virtual box). I check the connection.

```
    lloret@lloret-VirtualBox:~/temp/JavaSDKv2$ ping 192.168.2.203
    PING 192.168.2.203 (192.168.2.203) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 192.168.2.203: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=2.56 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.2.203: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1.64 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.2.203: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=1.56 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.2.203: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=1.34 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.2.203: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=1.60 ms
```

And I check the java version (java -version)

```
lloret@lloret-VirtualBox:~/temp/JavaSDKv2$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
 lloret@lloret-VirtualBox:~/temp/JavaSDKv2$ javac com/impinj/octanesdk/samples/*.java -classpath OctaneSDKJava-1.20.2.240-jar-with-dependencies.jar
lloret@lloret-VirtualBox:~/temp/JavaSDKv2$
```

(and this creates the .class files)

```
lloret@lloret-VirtualBox:~/temp/JavaSDKv2$ java -Dhostname=192.168.2.203 -classpath OctaneSDKJava-1.20.2.240-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.impinj.octanesdk.samples.RfDoppler
Error: Could not find or load main class com.impinj.octanesdk.samples.RfDoppler
lloret@lloret-VirtualBox:~/temp/JavaSDKv2$
```

Strangely java doesn't find any kind of .class file.
My guess is that is something related to the package.
Of course if someone writes a helloworld.java code and the executes the helloworld.class, you see "Hello, World!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On ubuntu your default classpath does not contain the current directory, so try it this way:

`lloret@lloret-VirtualBox:~/temp/JavaSDKv2$ java -Dhostname=192.168.2.203 -classpath OctaneSDKJava-1.20.2.240-jar-with-dependencies.jar:. com.impinj.octanesdk.samples.RfDoppler`